# Easiest way to deploy a rails app developed in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, rubymine

I developed a Rails app in RubyMine.  I'd like to deploy it utilizng Heroku, AWS, or some other service that isn't too expensive.  I have searched for hours on the web for a tutorial or instructions or *something* that explains how to do this, to no avail.  People must have done this.  I'd appreciate any help.

I also tried just doing it from scratch going to Heroku.  But Heroku wants JRuby and JDK 8, which I don't know how to sync with RubyMine.  It also doesn't want SQLLite3, I'll work on getting that going in my app.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have read this right? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4

Comment: Yes.  Have used RubyMine and then chosen and successfully deployed it on Heroku, AWS, or other service?

Comment: If you're asking me if I've deployed a rails app to heroku, yes I have. I don't use RubyMine but it shouldn't be any different than using any other Text Editor. You're going to have to go to the command line and use `git push heroku master` and `heroku open` to take a look at your deployed app. Sorry man, I just followed the tutorial on the site. If i find anything else I'll post.

Comment: Why don't you put it as an answer.  Heroku has another page that sent me down the wrong track.  The one you sent me was better and I did get it done.  :)

Comment: glad to hear it my friend. I'll post the link as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it doesn't matter what text editor you use to deploy to Heroku. Following the basic tutorial on the site should be able to get it done.

[Deploy to Heroku: Rails 4.x tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Comment: Well, RubyMine is more than a text editor, it is an IDE.  It is similar to Eclipse, but with lots of features specialized for Ruby on Rails developers.  That said, the link worked.  :)